# AWS cli started failing randomly today...?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, devops

On a linux server:

> ```
> File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module> 
>    import awscli.clidriver
> ImportError: No module named awscli.clidriver
> ```

Any idea why this could have started happening?

Comment: Look 2 last comments here, https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1255, I got into that situation also.

Comment: In case it's related: I installed awscli with "sudo pip install --upgrade --user awscli". And if I tried "aws --version" I'd get: ImportError: No module named 'awscli'. The way it works now is if I invoke it with the full path and sudo, something like: "sudo /home/username/.local/bin//aws --version

Answer (score 0):

Current execution context is not aware of the python's environment preferences.

All you have to do is to assign `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before you execute `awscli` command.

Example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages 

# For example list files from your bucket
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive
```

In order to set correct path for `PYTHONPATH` you need to check where are the python packages are installed on your computer/server.
Above example is from my ubuntu 16.04 server were python2.7 is installed by compiling python's source code.

Depending on how python is installed, you should search for one of the folders `site-packags` or `dist-packages` which contains list of installed python packages.

Also, on another server I've found that required package are on following  location:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Here is the example what is located inside my `site-packages` folder.
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rluR0.png)